# unixODBC fails on mac with "[IM004] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed"

Tags: macos, odbc

I am trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL server from an ARM mac running macOS 11.0.1.

I have set up a conda environment with a miniconda install, and from within a Jupyter notebook I run:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=xxx;Database=xxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx;')

Error: ('IM004', "[IM004] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Running odbcinst -j shows no obvious issue. I think the issue is in my environment somewhere:

```
$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.9
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/johnmorgan/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8

$ more /etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib
UsageCount=1

[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
UsageCount=1
```

My $PATH is:

```
$ tr ':' '\n' <<< "$PATH"
/opt/anaconda3/envs/analysis/bin
/opt/miniconda3/bin
/opt/anaconda3/condabin
/Users/johnmorgan/anaconda3/bin
/Users/johnmorgan/anaconda3/bin
/Users/johnmorgan/anaconda2/bin
/Users/johnmorgan/anaconda/bin
//anaconda/bin
/Users/johnmorgan/anaconda/bin
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/Applications/anaconda/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/opt/X11/bin
/Library/Apple/usr/bin
/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin
```

All help appreciated.

Comment: Further, I notice the environment variables ODBCSYSINI and ODBCINI are not set.  Per [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/%5Bisql%5Derror-could-not-sqlconnect-mongo-database-4175642938/) post I have set them to line up with my odbcinst -j output:
```
export ODBCSYSINI=/etc
export ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini
```
This hasn't helped.

Also, checking the data sources might suggest another point of failure:
```
$ odbcinst -q -s
odbcinst: SQLGetPrivateProfileString failed with .
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue.

According to this comment the error is commonly due to a missing resource file:
https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/738

The required resource file is msodbcsqlr17.rll, according to the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15

This the documentation indicates the resource file should be located in:
/usr/local/share/msodbcsql17/resources/en_US

(or possibly a different location, relative to the location of the driver file, see the documentation link above)

For some reason my resource file was missing.

I located a copy by inspecting the home-brew formula at:
https://github.com/microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release/blob/master/Formula/msodbcsql17%4017.1.0.1.rb

This contains the download link:
https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/9/A/19AF548A-6DD3-4B48-88DC-724E9ABCEB9A/msodbcsql-17.1.0.1.tar.gz

Within the zipped package there is a copy of msodbcsqlr17.rll

I copied this to /usr/local/share/msodbcsql17/resources/en_US

And the problem is resolved.

Comment: Short update: The same error reappeared after updating the vpn client Tunnelblick.  msodbcsqlr17.rll was removed from /usr/local/share/msodbcsql17/resources/en_US, and replacing it as above fixed the problem.